# How to update the Site Title and description of modern team site?

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, office-365-developer

Is there any way to update the SharePoint Online **Modern team site** "***Title***" using Rest API or graph API.

I tried the below code, but it is not updating.

```
 import { Web } from "sp-pnp-js";

let web = new Web("https://company.sharepoint.com/sites/sitename");

web.update({
    Title: "New Title",   
    Description: "My new description"
}).then(w => {

    console.log(w);
});
```

I figured out that Microsoft is using `https://company.sharepoint.com/sites/sitename/_api/SP.Directory.DirectorySession/Group('GroupID')` this api to get the properties and update the properties. But I cannot use this as it is not documented.

Is there any API which will update the title and description at group level?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, a SharePoint modern site is automatically connected to a Office 365 Group. We can use [Azure Active Directory Graph API to update group properties](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/group_update), then it will sync to the modern site.

Request:

```
PATCH https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/{id}
Content-type: application/json
Content-length: 211

{
  "description": "description-value",
  "displayName": "displayName-value",
  "groupTypes": [
    "Unified"
  ]  
}
```

[Working with groups in Microsoft Graph](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/resources/groups-overview)

Comment: Thank you Joanna. I tried this code and it is updating, but it is taking too long to reflect in the site.

Comment: Indeed. Is there any way to make this sync faster?